# Adding and removing input fields with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a problem while adding input fields with jQuery.

I set limit to 5 input fields. But if i try to remove input fields, my limit dont work . 
My var x when i use x-- is not proper decrement, for example if i have 5 input fields and when i  click to remove one input , var x is -4 instead -1.

Can someone help me to solve this problem. My code is:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var max = 5;
    var x = 0;
    $('#add').click(function(e) {  
        if(x < max) {
            $('#inp').append('<div><input class = "new_input" type=text name="name[]" placeholder="Unesite podatak"/><a class="remove_field "href="#"> X</a><div><br/>');
            x++;
        }
        $('.remove_field').click( function(e) {   
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;   
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: is this `$('.remove_field').click( function(e){..` working for you?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: 5-1 is 4 , so what is the problem

Comment: @Roshanjha http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/406tj3f4/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny ok I got it. Actually it was not clear from the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are adding the remove handler inside the add handler instead of using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). So the previously added remove elements will get multiple remove handlers causing x to be decremented multiple times

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    var max = 5;
    var x = 0;
    $('#add').click(function (e) {
        if (x < max) {
            $('#inp').append('<div><input class = "new_input" type=text name="name[]" placeholder="Unesite podatak"/><a class="remove_field "href="#"> X</a><div><br/>');
            x++;
        }
    });
    $('#inp').on('click', '.remove_field', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="inp"></div>
```

Problem: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/406tj3f4/1/)

Comment: i got it error undifined is not fuction for this line $('#inp').on('click', '.remove_field', function (e) {

Comment: @VladimirŠtus jQuery version used

Comment: sholud i use $('.remove_field')

Comment: @VladimirŠtus where do you want to use `$('.remove_field') `

Comment: @VladimirŠtus can you reproduce the problem using jsfiddle or code snippets

Comment: u got it on http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/406tj3f4/1/ try to add 5 inputs and then remove 5 inputs, then again add inputs. Second time limit is no more 5, so u can add million inputs, and that what i want to prevent.

Comment: tnx you sir! issue was in old version of jquery wich i used, probably it doesnt support on click event!. Again tnx a lot! You really help me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example, 
See this link

```
http://jsfiddle.net/vh3Js/
```

Hope this will help you.

HTML :

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        <input type="button" class="btnDel" value="Delete" disabled="disabled" />
        <input type="text" name="input1" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var inputs = 1; 

    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        $('.btnDel:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
        var c = $('.clonedInput:first').clone(true);
            c.children(':text').attr('name','input'+ (++inputs) );
        $('.clonedInput:last').after(c);
    });

    $('.btnDel').click(function() {
        if (confirm('continue delete?')) {
            --inputs;
            $(this).closest('.clonedInput').remove();
            $('.btnDel').attr('disabled',($('.clonedInput').length  < 2));
        }
    });


});
```