# How do I remove an input field after it's being emptied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding input fields on keystroke, by using an example from the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059023/adding-and-removing-input-fields-with-jquery). This is my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/bembvptx/). I was trying in various ways to remove field if user deletes content from it, so that there are always fields that have some content and one last empty field for adding more, but I just can't find a solution.

This is the code:

```
$(document.body).on("input", ".external-media-input:last", function () {
    var inputID = (parseInt($(this).attr('id')) + 1);
    $(".input_fields_wrap").append('<div><input class="external-media-input" id="' + inputID + '" name="external_media[]" type="text"/></div>');
});
```

Comment: `remove field if user deletes content from it` this not clear?what you mean is if the input becomes empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`on('blur')`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) or [`.on('focusout')`](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

```
//...
.on('blur', ".external-media-input:not(:last)", function () {
    if(!$(this).val()) $(this).remove();
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bembvptx/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can use also `on('keyup')`

```
$(document.body).on("keyup", ".external-media-input", function(){
    if($(this).val() == '') 
       $(this).remove(); 
});
```

here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bembvptx/2/

Answer (score 1):

In your style add one more event:

```
$(document.body).on("input", ".external-media-input", function () {
  if (!$(this).val())
  {
   $(this).remove();
  }
});
```